# How to save the result of the select in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to save the result of the select statment from Snowflake in AWS Lambda. I want to print the value but I don't know how. The goal is to return in print statment number 1

```
def run_query(conn, query):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()

    statement_6= "select 1"
    number = run_query(conn,statement_6)
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should never reach the `print(number)` statement. The code is more or less like an endless loop, because the `run_query()` method is recursively calling itself. Since there is no `return` statement, this will create an endless loop and never reach the `print` statement.

Since you provided no further information, I only can guess that you are using Python with Postgres and `psycopg`.

You could try this:

```py
def run_query(conn, query):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    for record in cursor:
        print record

    cursor.close()
```

Somewhere in your code (since you did not provide any I have to guess again), you need to run something like this:

```py
run_query(conn, "select 1")
```

The important thing to remember is, that you can not call `run_query` in your `run_query` function.